# Rails automated testing of POROs in a app/lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to include some additional non-rails classes in my Rails App. I created a lib directory under app/ and a lib directory under test/ I am using minitest.

How do I make it so `rails test` also runs the tests under the new test/lib directory? How do I make it so my app includes app/lib in the autoload mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

In the application.rb file add the following configuration which will load files from the app/lib folder

```
config.autoload_paths += "#{Rails.root}/app/lib/"
```

Comment: generally, we add the lib folder outside of the app folder under the root directory

Comment: Really? Interesting. It turns out that if I put it under app/ then it all works automagically.